# Startup image in webapp for Retina display?

Tags: iphone, ios4, mobile-safari

Anybody know how to get iOS to display higher resolution startup image when using  ? Currently I'm stuck with 460x380 image which obviously looks horrible when displayed on iPhone 4's high dpi display. I tried the @2x trick but didn't seem to work.

Any ideas or workarounds?

Comment: How are you showing the startup image? are you using default.png file?

Comment: If you check Apple's documentation at http://bit.ly/95IHsf, they say that picture has to be 320 x 460 pixels and in portrait orientation. I notice I messed up the resolution in the question but I did it with 320x460 and got it to work. Documentation doesn't say anything about retina display so I'm not sure if it's outdated, hence my question.

Comment: Satyam svv, I'm using startup.png and I tried to put highres version as startup@2x.png but didn't work. I'm using link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" tag.

Comment: Crispy - just checking if you've found an answer to this question (the last comment/answer was almost a year ago). Apple's documentation still states that the image MUST BE 320x460...

Answer (score 21):

I didn't ever think I would get this working, but for some reason, everywhere online states that the hi-res images dimensions are 640x960, they are actually 640x920. When you make this change, the hi-res splash screen will appear correctly on retina displays. Below is the exact code that I use in our app. We have splash screens working on iPad1/iPad2 Portrait and Landscape, iPhone3/iPhone4

Hope this helps someone.

```
  <!-- iOS Device Startup Images -->
<!-- iPhone/iPod Touch Portrait – 320 x 460 (standard resolution) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" href="splash-screen-320x460.png" media="screen and (max-device-width: 320px)" />

<!-- iPhone/iPod Touch Portrait – 640 x 920 pixels (high-resolution) -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" media="(max-device-width: 480px) and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)" href="splash-screen-640x920.png" />

<!-- For iPad Landscape 1024x748 -->
  <!-- Note: iPad landscape startup image has to be exactly 748x1024 pixels (portrait, with contents rotated).-->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="1024x748" href="splash-screen-1024x748.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:landscape)" />

<!-- For iPad Portrait 768x1004 -->
<link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="splash-screen-768x1004.png" media="screen and (min-device-width: 481px) and (max-device-width: 1024px) and (orientation:portrait)"/>
```

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using media queries related to pixel ratio on the `link` tag?

`media="only screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio: 2)"` for the retina display one.

Comment: It's a clever idea, but even without the media attribute, a 640x920 image doesn't work on a retina display. I think it's likely that it's just not supported right now. At least ion my tests, I haven't managed it. See the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/safari/#documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/ConfiguringWebApplications/ConfiguringWebApplications.html). Hopefully they'll add it in a later iOS version.

Comment: Damn too bad, just getting around to setting up the start screen for my app now and it looks grainy.

Answer (score 0):

iPad:

```
link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="768x1004" href="" /
iPhone Retina Display: link rel="apple-touch-startup-image" sizes="640x960" href="" /
```

Answer (score -1):

I've seen cases where XCode messes up in this situation. In addition to double checking the image size, (320x460) it doesn't hurt to:

1. Make sure both images are in the build. (Right/Option click on the files header and select "target membership" and then make sure the checkbox is checked.)
2. Do a clean build.
3. Delete all of the build files in your build directory. (Clean doesn't get ALL of them.)
4. Delete the app from the target phone/sim.

I know this may seem obvious or unnecessary, but I banged my head against the same problem and the clean/delete/delete sequence fixed it.

Comment: He was talking about web apps, not native apps.

Answer (score -3):

The "@2x" trick works. Must have been something wrong with your images.

You want two files. Default.png and Default@2x.png. The first one should be 320x460. The second should be 640x920. I promise it works.

Comment: Nope.. doesn't work for some reason. Now I have Default.png and Default@2x.png and I have verified the sizes of both. It always loads Default.png. I verified this from my development server's logs and it doesn't even send a request for @2x version. I must be missing something here... *edit* You are talking about startup/splash image for webapp and not your average img tag image on the webpage, right? :)

Comment: I'm talking about the splash screen for a NATIVE app. Is that what you're asking about? I see you used the word "webapp" in the title of the question, but everything else you've written has been as if you were making a native app... The @2x thing is for native apps. In Obj-C, built with Xcode.

Comment: Ah, I'm talking about webapp you use via Mobile Safari. I was under impression that in iOS4 Mobile Safari tries to check for @2x images also.